# Homebrew can't brew upgrade, warning: You are using macOS 13. We do not provide support for this pre-release version

Tags: homebrew, macos-ventura

I upgrade MacOS Ventura 13. When I brew install git, appeared error:

```
Warning: You are using macOS 13.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
```

Comment: After updating to macOS Ventura, make sure to check in your Xcode - Preferences - Locations - If the Command Line Tools is selected in the dropdown. Mine was empty after the update.

Comment: when i meet this problem last month , I figure out just install the beta Xcode 14 can solve this problem

Answer (score 17):

Updating the homebrew itself would resolved the issue.

Run `brew update` before running `brew upgrade`

Comment: The brew update command itself will fail because of an outdated version. Rather try this -                       

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Answer (score 10):

Brew suggests a couple of possible solutions:

```
Warning: Your Command Line Tools (CLT) does not support macOS 13.
It is either outdated or was modified.
Please update your Command Line Tools (CLT) or delete it if no updates are available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/all/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.1.
```

The first and second suggestion didn't work for me at this time of writing. Trying the third suggestion, so downloading CLT RC2 via https://developer.apple.com/download/all/, did do the trick.

You can confirm this afterwards by running `brew doctor`. That CLT warning should no longer be there.

Comment: Installing CLT RC2 also worked for me - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just go to https://brew.sh, and reinstall from there

Comment: Reinstalling resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just upgrade to macOS Somano, then I got that issue. I solved the problem :

> brew update-reset

Answer (score 1):

Actually upgrading brew should fix the issue, as https://brew.sh/2022/09/07/homebrew-3.6.0/ has preliminary support.

---

For some reason, In my experience brew itself was not functioning properly i.e brew update and brew upgrade did not work.
So, I uninstalled and reinstalled brew version 3.6.10.

Try and it should fix the issue.

Comment: Hey. I have the same issue with `update` and `upgrade` - were you able to find a way to uninstall and reinstall without having to reinstall all your packages?

Answer (score 1):

I go to https://developer.apple.com/account and download the up-to-date 'command line tools for Xcode XX'. By my time, I downloaded Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_15_beta_7.dmg. It works.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your version of BREW is outdated.

Run the following command on Linux/mac to upgrade Brew -

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's use:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: this is right comment generally, but this time isn't.
XCode 14.1 is not released yet, so if you want to install 14.1, you need to install XCode RC2 like answer below.